# convert table to normal range in excel power query

Tags: excel, powerquery

i want to convert table into normal range .
if i am convert table into range this will remove query definition from the sheet permanently

[img] https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGkHd.png

power query code:

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table310"]}[Content],
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(Source,{{"instrument_key", "Symbol1"}}),
#"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Symbol.1", each Symbol([Symbol1])),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Invoked Custom Function",{"symbol", "year", "W/M", "Strike", "Option", "Symbol1", "tradingsymbol", "Lot"}),
#"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Columns"),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Transposed Table", "Custom", each Table.FromColumns(Table.ToColumns([Column1]) & Table.ToColumns([Column2]) & Table.ToColumns([Column3]))),
#"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Custom", {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23", "Column24", "Column25", "Column26", "Column27", "Column28", "Column29", "Column30", "Column31", "Column32", "Column33", "Column34", "Column35", "Column36", "Column37", "Column38", "Column39"}, {"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7", "Column8", "Column9", "Column10", "Column11", "Column12", "Column13", "Column14", "Column15", "Column16", "Column17", "Column18", "Column19", "Column20", "Column21", "Column22", "Column23", "Column24", "Column25", "Column26", "Column27", "Column28", "Column29", "Column30", "Column31", "Column32", "Column33", "Column34", "Column35", "Column36", "Column37", "Column38", "Column39"}),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Expanded Custom", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Date", type datetime}, {"open", type number}, {"high", type number}, {"low", type number}, {"close", type number}, {"volume", Int64.Type}, {"oi", Int64.Type}, {"avg price", type number}, {"avgpricecprcnt", type number}, {"coi", type any}, {"Nt", Int64.Type}, {"coint", type any}, {"mf", Int64.Type}, {"Date_1", type datetime}, {"open_2", type number}, {"high_3", type number}, {"low_4", type number}, {"close_5", type number}, {"volume_6", Int64.Type}, {"oi_7", Int64.Type}, {"avg price_8", type number}, {"avgpricecprcnt_9", type number}, {"coi_10", Int64.Type}, {"Nt_11", Int64.Type}, {"coint_12", Int64.Type}, {"mf_13", type number}, {"Date_14", type datetime}, {"open_15", type number}, {"high_16", type number}, {"low_17", type number}, {"close_18", type number}, {"volume_19", Int64.Type}, {"oi_20", Int64.Type}, {"avg price_21", type number}, {"avgpricecprcnt_22", type number}, {"coi_23", Int64.Type}, {"Nt_24", Int64.Type}, {"coint_25", Int64.Type}, {"mf_26", type number}})     in #"Changed Type"
```

i want to keep query difinition and convert table into normal range

Comment: You cannot do that, and certainly not in Power Query. You could, in Excel (or VBA)  **`Copy/Paste as Values`** to a different range which would provide the table data in a non-table range

Answer (score 2):

‘Unlinking’ the table from the query, for example as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/70804179 leaves the data as a ‘normal’ table and retains the query definition in the file but it will be a connection only. Then you can convert the table to a range.